# What does x(#) mean in government statistical publications?

Tags: notation

I am analyzing some UNESCO data on education and I came across the notation of "x(10)" or more generally "x(somenumber)" as cell values in their official spreadsheets such as [this one](http://uis.unesco.org/sites/default/files/datacentre/Educational_attainment_-_Niveau_d%27%C3%A9ducation_atteint.xlsx). Surprisingly, google did not turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can find the answer at the bottom of the Excel sheet:

[image: Screenshot from Excel]

Comment:  thanks! I thought this was a common notation.